# Mobile CSS navigation click events

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

Im trying to make my first mobile first site and i'm having a slight problem with my onclick even when u click menu.  When u click the menu icon and the drop down occurs the, the screen drops a bit showing only part of the header.  How do u make it so , so that when u click menu the screen doesnt drop or scroll down a bit.  you can see in my example i put up what i mean, any ideas, any help is much appreciated heres my demo link:

Demo: http://cssdeck.com/labs/jkxsecgl

here's my HTML markup:

```
      <body>
<div id="container">

    <div id="header">
    <h1>This is the header</h1>
    <div class="main-nav" id="nav">
      <a href="#nav" class="nav-open"> &#9776; Menu</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-close"> &#9776; Close</a>
          <nav>
              <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">bio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>

    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="content"><h1>This is the content</h1></div>
    <aside><h1>The side bar</h1></aside>
    <footer><h1>The Footer</h1></footer>


    <div id="content"><h1>This is the content</h1></div>
    <aside><h1>The side bar</h1></aside>
    <footer><h1>The Footer</h1></footer>

</div>


</body>
```

CSS:

```
*{margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}

h1 {padding: 10px;}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 320px;
    background: rgba(51,0,255,.2);
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

#nav {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#nav nav ul, .nav-close, .nav-open {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-close {
  display: none;
}


#nav nav ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-open, .nav-close {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#nav:target .nav-open {
  display: none;
}

#nav:target .nav-close {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav nav {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}
#nav nav ul {
    position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 0;
        max-width: 16em;
            max-width: 16em;
        background: #f6f6f6;
        border-width: 0px;
        border-style: dashed;
        border-color: #aaa;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: max-height linear 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: max-height linear 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: max-height linear 0.5s;
        -o-transition: max-height linear 0.5s;
        transition: max-height linear 0.5s;

}
#nav nav ul li {
        display: block;
    background: orange;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;   
}
#nav nav ul li a {
        padding: 0.3em 1.5em;
    }
#nav:target nav ul {
        max-height: 400px;
    }
.nav-open {
        display: inline-block;
    }

#header {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,204,51,.7);  
}

#content {
    background: rgba(0,0,204,.6);
    height: 300px;  
    }

aside {
    background: rgba(153,0,0,0.9);
    height: 300px;
    }   

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;  
    background: rgba(102,255,255,1);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is thats the default action of an anchor tag, you could probably override this with js but that might go against what your trying to do here. AKA css only

Comment: here's the navigation example that i'm using. he uses the same default tag but his is not moving when clicked,  http://jeffri.me/2012/11/pure-css3-responsive-navigation-with-target/ , notice how when u click menu, the screen doesn't drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tom said...that is the default action of your anchor tags...Because there is a hash (#) in the href attribute, it is attempting to jump to that location.  You need to use JavaScript to override the functionality of the anchor tag, or just live with the jumping. And yes...the example you gave jumps too.  He is jumping to "#nav" when open is clicked and "#" when close is clicked...if you resize his screen so that you have to scroll, you will see it occur.

To go the JS route, you can use onclick in the tag itself and return false, or you can use jQuery and use preventDefault.

Outside of that, I don't know of a way to do it purely with CSS and prevent the "jumping."

Comment: and not ONLY that when the container is smaller than the screen size, THEN it doesnt JUMP at all SO it HAS NOTHING to do with THE hash tag

Comment: Bro...are you kidding me? On THIS demonstration (http://projects.keaglez.com/navigation/)  Reduce your browser screen size (height as well so that you can scroll down), scroll down, click the open button and THEN close it.  The entire page jumps back to the top.  Don't question my professionalism when you are obviously the one who doesn't understand how HTML anchors work.

Comment: http://projects.keaglez.com/navigation/#  << LOOK AT MINE AND LOOK AT HIS MINE DROPS TO THE BOTTOM JACK READ WHAT IM SAYING BEFORE U ANSWER I"m NOT talking about MOVING BACK ON TOP NOW LOOK AT MY EXAMPLE http://cssdeck.com/labs/jkxsecgl MINE drops down the header half way WHEN u CLICK MENU

Comment: AND SECONDLY IT DOESNT JUMP AT ALL WHEN there is NO content IN the side bar, content or footer

Comment: Yours is performing the exact same way his is...it is jumping to #nav on open and # on close...if you can't see that, I can't help you.  The fact that your design is different is the only reason you are seeing the movement at all on yours on open.

Comment: LOLO NO ITS NOT god u really dont SEE

Comment: BRO LOOK AT HIS EXAMPLE IF U CLICK MENU THE SCREEN DOESNT JUMP DOWN IF U CLICK MINE IT MOVES DOWN  A BIT DO U SEE WHAT IM SAYING ITS NOT THE EXACTLY THE SAME

Comment: I really don't know how else to explain this to you outside of what I have already said.  Anchors attempt to jump the location provided...'#nav' is jumping to the location of the nav div on the page...'#' is jumping back to the top.  That is why you are seeing the movement...his nav is already at the very top so you are not seeing the movement on his.  The jump on close is due to the anchor looking for '#' which is the TOP of the page by default. Hence why his jumps on close but not on open.

Comment: thank u now i understand u shouldve said that in the first place :P u know ur stuff lol should i just use javascript for click events? on navigation thanks again :P

Comment: how would u over ride that? with JS? u got any links that have information on that?

Comment: The same way I said in the answer...use jquery and use preventDefault, or use JS with no jQuery and just use an onclick event and 'return false'. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Glad it helped...if it answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I threw something together after a little thinking: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ok437d8l still not the best approach

Answer (score 1):

I had a look after thinking about this an although I still believe JS to be a better solution, this might help: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ok437d8l i moved all your target tags to the #container. Which is the container element so the anchor point is at the top.

But it will jump to the top if your scroll away.

Comment: thanks man i'll check it out  appreciate it, it's all good im just going to use javascript or i'll use the checkbox method from which i heard is better csstricks talks about anchor jumping when u use target  and should be used when u DO need a jump here's the link if anyone is interested http://css-tricks.com/on-target/ , and another link for css3 click events with pros and cons of each method http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/